# Spring shell with groovy

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-shell

I have my class:

```
package com.ejemplo.prueba;

import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellMethod

@ShellComponent
class MyShellCommands {

    @ShellMethod("Este es un comando de ejemplo")
    def myCommand() {
        return "¡Hola desde Groovy!"
    }
}
```

But when I execute the shell, it's fail:

> shell:>myCommand No command found for 'myCommand'

My depencies maven in pom are:

Springoot 3.1.4 and Spring shell 3.1.3 and

The execution in shell should show:

> ¡Hola desde Groovy!

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/docs/index.html) if you don't specify the `key` attribute of `@ShellMethod` annotation, then per default you camelCase `myCommand` gets converted to kebap case (`my-command`).

- Either define it yourself: `@ShellMethod(key = "myCommand", value = "Este es un comando de ejemplo")`
- or use the auto generated version `my-command` from the commandline.

Try also using `help` to see the list of available commands